# C Programming: function returned -1, but got 255 after `echo $?`

Tags: c

File `main.c`:

```
int main(void) {
    return -1;
}
```

In bash, run the command: `gcc main.c; ./a.out; echo $?`.

I expected the output is `-1`, but I got `255`.
Why? The return type of `main` is `int`, but how can it overflow to `255`?

Comment: Probably unrelated: according to [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html) the exit code "must be an integer in the 0 - 255 range"

Comment: Actually better, but semi off-site: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37915/why-do-i-get-error-255-when-returning-1